# Internal working of RDBMS

Tags: oracle10g, rdbms

I have a table with 10 columns and I wish to select column 1 and column 9 from the table. In RDBMS how many columns shall be selected internally?

Comment: I am asking about Oracle and I am studying hbase due to which I got confused a little bit. I am not a database guy rather I am a java guy and I am now into Hadoop and I have not touched databases since a year long. Reasons are many let's not discuss it. By the way thank you for the comment. I am well aware of what am I upto. I am a novice MR programmer but I am doing well with my part of coding.

Comment: So, I guess its better to read books first and ask the questions next because due to the questions the technical qualifiications get questioned by the way ;which is not expected. I just wanted to clear my doubts about databases not about the content of my profile

Comment: http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=5001&get_params=p_exam_id:1Z0-851      Have a look at this link. The OCJP has no relations with the DBMS part,

Comment: This is asks about properties of some particular DBMS product & version *implementation*. Thanks for clarifying that you mean Oracle; please edit appropriate Oracle & other tag(s) into your question. Please also explain what "selected internally" means. (I understand that internally addresses the implementation.) (Notice that you are presuming some aspects of implementation just to use that phrase.) It would probably be helpful i if you described the context, assumptions and reason/concerns/query leading to your question.

Comment: @AniruddhaSinha: You should update the question to clarify the context; you could consider adding Oracle as a tag.  However, the question is really very broad — too broad to make a good question on SO.  Whole books have been written on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the fundamental ideas behind the Relational Model is that RDBMS users characterize their problems in terms of tables & queries representing abstract application relationships and describing abstract application states while the RDBMS interface *hides* (as much as possible) table & query implementation by another such "logical" RDBMS layer or by other, "physical", paradigm layers. (Hence, logical and physical [*data independence*](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/zaiane/material/notes/Chapter1/node15.html).)

Your question can only be answered about a particular implementation of a particular version of a particular DBMS. You can find DBMS implementation discussed in textbooks & slides, of which there are numerous sites & .pdfs online.

If this is a performance concern: It just isn't the sort of thing you should worry about until you are familiar with schema design and querying as well as basic performance issues like indexing. Googling: Oracle's .pdf [Oracle Database SQL Tuning Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/E49106-08.pdf). Bookboon's free online downloadable ebook [Database Design and Implementation: A practical introduction using Oracle SQL](http://bookboon.com/en/database-design-and-implementation-ebook).

Comment: thankyou but I thought that RDBMS is purticularly taken to be oracle... yet postgreSQL does have a stand but  I have been working in Oracle and MySQL and to my knowledge mySql can't be called as a pure RDBMS application

Comment: They are all SQL databases, meaning they supply most of the SQL standard plus their own addtions. That is relational as one gets commercially to "relational". SQL can be used relationally but there is so much more power and simplicitiy to the Relational Model than it offers. Google SQL vs relational.

Answer (score 1):

RDBMS stores table datas in rows and rows in pages.
RDBMS can indexes table datas.
Internally the RDBMS reads row by row in an index or a table.

So the problem is to know if there is an index or not.

In the case where there is no index at all for the table, all the columns needs to be read, because the table row is compound of all the columns

In the case where and index has just exactly the twos columns, only the twos columns plus a reference to the table rows place is read.

In the case where an index have the two columns plus some more columns, this index will be choose by the optimizer and conducts to read some more informations, but less than the table row.

In some special case, due to the optimizer (in the "bigs" RDBS like SQL Server…) if there is two indexes , one containing the first column and the other the second , the two indexes can be read concurrently and a final join is executed.